# Python - Pytest TypeError

Tags: python, testes

Estou montando o pytest da função calcular da classe Soma de uma calculadora, mas como a função calcular recebe um "objeto" como argumento, está dando erro.
 Segue os códigos.

Inputs:

```
def main():
    operation = input('''
Por favor, selecione a opção que gostaria de realizar:
SOMA para adição
SUBTRAÇÃO para subtração
''')

    number_1 = int(input('Por favor, inserir o primeiro número: '))
    number_2 = int(input('Por favor, inserir o segundo número: '))

    parametros = ParametrosCalculo(operation, number_1, number_2)
    resultado = Calculadora().preparar(parametros).calcular()

    print(f'O seu resultado é: {resultado}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
class ParametrosCalculo(object):
    def __init__(self, operacao, p1, p2):
        self.operacao = operacao
        self.parametro1 = p1
        self.parametro2 = p2

class Operacao(object):
    def __init__(self, p1, p2):
        self.p1 = p1
        self.p2 = p2

    def calcular(self):
        raise Exception('Operacao não é!')

class Soma(Operacao):
    def calcular(self):
        return self.p1 + self.p2

class Subtracao(Operacao):
    def calcular(self):
        return self.p1 - self.p2

class FabricaOperacoes(object):
    @staticmethod
    def criar(parametros_operacao: ParametrosCalculo):
        if parametros_operacao.operacao == 'soma':
            return Soma(parametros_operacao.parametro1, parametros_operacao.parametro2)
        if parametros_operacao.operacao == 'subtracao':
            return Subtracao(parametros_operacao.parametro1, parametros_operacao.parametro2)

        raise Exception('Operacao inválida!')

class Calculadora(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.preparada = False

    def preparar(self, parametros_calculo):
        self.parametros_calculo = parametros_calculo
        self.operacao = FabricaOperacoes.criar(parametros_calculo)
        self.preparada = True

        return self

    def calcular(self):
        return self.operacao.calcular()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

A sua funcao calcular nao recebe dois argumentos. Se estou entendendo seu codigo direito, voce tem que criar um objeto `Operacao`, e passar esse objeto para a construcao do objeto `Soma`.

Quando construir o objeto `Soma`, chame calcula: `soma.calcular()`

Nao sei qual o seu objetivo com esse codigo. Mas ele me parece muito complicado. Ele pode ser simplificado.

Inves de ter Classes como `Soma`, `Subtracao`, etc. Essas classes podem ser metodos da classe `Operacao`, e os metodos `Soma`, `Subtracao`, etc poderiam receber os parametros para a operacao. Do jeito que voce esta fazendo, voce tem que criar um objeto `operacao` e `soma` toda vez que voce quer fazer uma operacao, e voce vai ter um stack overflow se fizer muitas dessas operacoes.

Comment: Sim, para testar o calcular() preciso criar o objeto que vem da classe Operação, mas estou com problema no código... Tenho que criar o objeto dentro da função de teste?

Comment: Acho que seria `Soma(Operacao).calcular()`